# Skip white space with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

So I am parsing a google spreadsheet and stuck at this problem:

```
$str = '‎20.00 €';
preg_match("/\d*.\d*/", $str, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

working example: 
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ggg

This is how it looks like: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14f9f8aa635f329f5b150b626d84da46746f064c

There is some white space which won't allow `preg_match` to find `20.00`. Don't know how to deal with it. I have tried `trim` but it won't work..

Comment: Try this one:-  **/\d+(\.\d+)?/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply escape that `.`

[DEMO](https://eval.in/598780)

```
preg_match("/\d*\.\d*/", $str, $output);
```

---

`.` Matches any character except line break in REGEX

Comment: Thanks. I did not know how to skip that dot.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove spaces in between the string using:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to escape the dot character.

```
$str = '‎20.00 €';
preg_match("/\d*\.\d*/", $str, $output);
var_dump($output);
```